# Polynomial fit through intercept zero - Ruby

Tags: ruby, math, matrix

I have to perform a polynomial fit but I have to force it to pass through intercept zero. How can I set it?

```
require 'matrix'
 
def regress x, y, degree
  x_data = x.map { |xi| (0..degree).map { |pow| (xi**pow).to_r } }
 
  mx = Matrix[*x_data]
  my = Matrix.column_vector(y)
 
  ((mx.t * mx).inv * mx.t * my).transpose.to_a[0].map(&:to_f)
end
```

Basically, the same when in Excel I check "Set Intercept" to zero

[image]

Comment: I don't believe this is fundamentally a Ruby question, and definitely not a Rails question, it's a matrix algebra question. I suggest you add the "matrix" tag and see if you can get the attention of someone with skills in that area.